# How can I make an ng-repeat filter that inserts the corresponding html and {{expression}} for each object?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Basically,

I have an array.

Some properties of each object in the array are different.

When ng-repeat iterates through the array, with a filter it should decide what html code to use, to display the preferred properties of each object with its own div classes.

```
(function() {
var app = angular.module('Veggies',[]);

app.controller('ArrayController', function(){ 
    this.Array = Array;
});   
var Vegetebles = [
    {Veg_name: 'Onion', price:2.95},
    {Veg_Article_Title: 'Garlic in Italy', year:20-10-2011},
    {Veg_name: 'Carrot', price:3.95},
    {Veg_name:'Celery', price:2.95},
    {Veg_Article_Title:'Lettuce Growing 101', year:20-10-2011},
    {Veg_name:'Pepper', price:3.95}
];
})();
```

What I need to achieve is the following:

Where if the object has a "Veg_Article_Title" key somewhere in it, then it is an article and should use the corresponding html code with its own div classes, that way it can be styled differently than an object that has a key of "Veg_name" and is a vegetable.

I tried doing this:

```
$scope.filter = function(Array){
    angular.forEach(Array,function(value, key){
        if (key === Veg_Article_Title){
        $scope.myHTML = 
        "<div class = "Article_Title"><h1>{{Object.Veg_Article_Title}}</h1></div>"
        "<div class = "Article_Year"><h2>{{Object.year}}</h2></div>";  
        }else (key === Veg_name){
        $scope.myHTML = 
        "<div class = "Vegeteble"><h1>{{Object.Veg_name}}</h1></div>"
        "<div class = "Vegeteble_Price"><h2>{{Object.price}}</h2></div>";         
    };
    }
```

I'm really not sure if I am approaching this problem right and couldn't find anything similar.

I am relatively new to coding, so please excuse any syntax errors.

Many Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Please iterate your array using ng-repeat directive.

**HTML Code:**

```
<div ng-repeat="d in Vegetebles">
    <div ng-if="d.Veg_name">Veg Name :  {{d.Veg_name}}</div> <!--Put your html if veg name found-->
    <div ng-if="d.Veg_Article_Title">Article Name : {{d.Veg_Article_Title}}</div> <!--Put your html if veg article title found-->
</div>
```

**JS Code inside controller:**

```
$scope.Vegetebles = [
            { Veg_name: 'Onion', price: 2.95 },
            { Veg_Article_Title: 'Garlic in Italy', year: 20 - 10 - 2011 },
            { Veg_name: 'Carrot', price: 3.95 },
            { Veg_name: 'Celery', price: 2.95 },
            { Veg_Article_Title: 'Lettuce Growing 101', year: 20 - 10 - 2011 },
            { Veg_name: 'Pepper', price: 3.95 }
        ];
```